# Character table of group $S_4$ and character of representation $\Lambda V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Well, I have a character table of group $S_4$:
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
 & \chi_1 & \chi_2 & \chi_3 & \chi_4 & \chi_5 \\
e & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\
(12) & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1   \\
(12)(34) & 1 & 1 & 2 & -1 & -1   \\
(123) & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0   \\
(1234) & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1   \\
  \end{array}
And I have a representation of $S_4$: $V=\chi_3^{\otimes 2} \otimes \chi_4^{\otimes 2} \oplus \chi_5^{\otimes 3}$. So, I need to find the character of this representation, and I've done this and I got: \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
 & V \\
e & 63 \\
(12) & 1 \\
(12)(34) & 3   \\
(123) & -   \\
(1234) & -1   \\
  \end{array}
And then I must find a character of $\Lambda^2 V$ and I've got a known formula to do it: $\chi_{\Lambda^2 V}(g)=\frac{\chi_{V}(g)^2-\chi_{V}(g^2)}2$ then I got:
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
& \Lambda^2 V \\
e & 3906 \\
(12) & -31 \\
(123) & 0   \\
(12)(34) & 4   \\
(1234) & -2   \\
  \end{array}
And I know that the character should be a integer number, but I got $-\frac{3}2$. Can someone explain where my mistake? May be I wrong counted a character of $V$.

Comment: What actually is $W$? To have $\frac12(\chi(e)^2-\chi(e^2))=0$ you need $\chi(e)=0$ or $1$; the representation is zero or one-dimensional.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I've a mistake, $V=W$, I'm corrected this.

Comment: That's a peculiar character table. The group $S_4$ has irreps of degrees $2$ and $3$, not just $1$.

Comment: I thought that $0-0=0$, not $-1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown My bad, it is one more mistake, I've corrected.

Comment: I'm still not convinced...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry, now it's right.

Comment: I don't think $\chi_4((1\,2))$ can equal $-1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, is equal $1$

Comment: I don't think that $\chi_4((1\,2\,3\,4))$ can equal $\chi_5((1\,2\,3\,4))$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry, a lot of mistakes, now it's right I think

Comment: I think that $\chi_3((1\,2)(3\,4))$ must equal $\chi_3(e)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown now?

Comment: Surely $\chi_4$ is the sign character? But $(1\,2)(3\,4)$ is an even permutation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $\chi_4$ is action on the cube and $\chi_5$ is action on a tetrahedron

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\chi_2$: I can get things wrong too!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No problem. Yes, $\chi_2$ is the sign character

Comment: so where is my mistake when counting the character of $\Lambda^2 V$

Comment: How can you subtract $0$ from $0$ and get $-3$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So, I'm confused , actually (123)^2 is not equal to (12)(34)?

Comment: I was wrong, actually is equal to (123)

Comment: Has $\bigwedge^2V$ really dimension zero?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown dimension of $\Lambda^2 V$ is $63^2-63= 3906$?

Comment: So, I've a new problem. When I'm trying to count the scalar product $<\chi_i,\Lambda^2 V>$ for $\chi_1 $ I got 155, but then for $\chi_2$ and $\chi_4$ I got 169,5 and 326,5.

Comment: That's because $\chi_2$ and $\chi_4$ aren't characters.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What it means?

Comment: Look at your character table. It has columns marked $\chi_2$ and $\chi_4$. The $\chi_2$ column is a function defined on $S_4$ but not a character. Likewise, the $\chi_4$ column is not a character. Is that clear enough?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown i.e $\chi_2 $ and $\chi_4$ is representation of a group $S_4$, not a character. But if I want to count multiplicities of irreducible representation in $\Lambda^2 V$, I must to calculate the scalar product. Or in this case I should firstly decompose  $\Lambda^2 V$ into irreducible?

Comment: Lord Shark is telling you your character table is **still** wrong. You can't do this problem unless you have a correct table. Where are you getting  your table from? A source? Are you working it out yourself? If so, how? Show  your work.

Comment: @anon I corrected my character table. First of all, We know that there exist the trivial representation and the sign representation, i.e $\chi_1$ and $chi_2$. Next step, we considering the 4-dimensional representation which has characters (4 2 1 0 0) and we can get of it $\chi_4=\chi - \chi_1$ and so on.

Comment: If $\chi_2$ is supposed to be the sign character, then your table is wrong: (123) is an even permutation (so $\chi_2=1$) and (1234) is an odd permutation $\chi_2=-1$. I haven't checked any of your other columns or looked at the edit history to see if you had it right at one point, but as long as you keep getting wrong answers you can assume you haven't finished correcting the table.

Comment: @anon I think now it's right, can you check?